# How do I encode/decode a file correctly after reading it through javascript and pass the file data through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-2.7

I have a django File field with multiple attribute set to true. I am trying to make a multiple file uploader where I get the file objects with a simple javascript FileReader object. After looping through the file list I read the file data through

```
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

and get the desired file data result. After passing this data to my views through ajax I am trying to create a copy of the file into the media folder. I am presently using the following views function :

```
@csrf_exempt
def storeAttachment(data):
    '''
    stores the files in media folder
    '''
    data = simplejson.loads(data.raw_post_data)
    user_org = data['user_org']
    fileName = data['fileName']
    fileData = data['fileData']
    file_path = MEDIA_ROOT + 'icts_attachments/'
    try:
        path = open((file_path+ str(user_org) + "_" + '%s')%fileName, "w+")
        path.write(fileData)
        path.close()
        return HttpResponse(1)
    except IOError:
        return HttpResponse(2)
```

I am able to write simple text files,.js,.html and other few formats but when I try to upload pdf, word, excel, rar formats I get the following error in my response even though a file with invalid data is saved at my MEDIA path(the file does not open).

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 41-42: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to encode/decode the file data using various references but with no effect..Any advice will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got error because `Python 2`'s default ASCII encoding was used. Characters greater than 127 cause an exception so use [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode from Unicode to text/bytes.

Good practice is to use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects.

```
path = u''.join((file_path, user_org, '_', fileName)).encode('utf-8')
with open(path, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(fileData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice...but after trying the above code the same error persists..

Comment: Did you get an error in line where `MEDIA_ROOT` appears?

Comment: Nope..Same error is shown in the response. The file gets saved in the MEDIA_ROOT directory..for pdf it shows an empty pdf file..for word files it shows the "general input-output error" and so on. So the file saves but with invalid content.